# Can't connect to schema with sqlacodegen

Tags: python, sqlacodegen

I'm trying to generate models using sqlacodegen and as an output I get only tables from public schema.
How can I retrive models from all tables and schemas?

sqlacodegen --outfile models.py postgres://user:passw@Host:Port/dbname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know I'm a bit late to the party, but if any else is looking for the answer:

You can append the argument

```
--schema [your_schema_name]
```

on to the end of thsqlacodegen command.

Comment: Please adjust your answers with correct syntax: --schemas